# "Verb" tag showing wrong count

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags

If you look at the [list of tags](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags?page=3), "verb" shows as being used only once. But if you [click on that tag](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/verb), you see that it's (currently) being used 16 times.

Is this possibly due to the existence of the [verb-agreement](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/verb) and [verb-forms](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/verb-forms) tags?

---

Edited to add:

It's not due to caching unless this site has the most extreme caching rules in existence. Here are some example questions—all over a week old—and when the "verb" tag was added to each:

- August 5:

  - ['shall' and 'will'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3/shall-and-will)
  - [Difference between lay and lie](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/105/difference-between-lay-and-lie)
- August 9:

  - [When is "L" doubled?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/338/when-is-l-doubled)
- August 11:

  - [What is the difference between 'll and will?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/445/what-is-the-difference-between-ll-and-will)
- August 12:

  - [Is "inactivate" really a word?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/568/is-inactivate-really-a-word)
  - [Why "mind" means "pay attention to"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/467/why-mind-means-pay-attention-to)
- August 13:

  - [Can "rather" be really used as a verb?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/688/can-rather-be-really-used-as-a-verb)
- August 16:

  - [Is there any difference between "talk to someone" and "talk with someone"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1029/is-there-any-difference-between-talk-to-someone-and-talk-with-someone)
  - [When should I use the subjunctive mood?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1066/when-should-i-use-the-subjunctive-mood)
  - [Future perfect progressive](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1069/future-perfect-progressive)

Or in other words, the count of the tag "verb" should have been over 1 for almost three weeks now…

Answer (score 2):

Most likely it is a caching issue. I just renamed the "verbs" tag to "verb" and the display is showing the previous tag display. The counts should display properly within the next few hours.